# ERROR: "filetest.submit" doesn't contain any "queue" commands -- no jobs queued

Tags: python, condor

I am writing a python script that creates a Condor submit file, writes information to it and then submits it to be run on Condor.

```
for f in my_range(0, 10, 2):
        condor_submit.write('Arguments = povray +Irubiks.pov +0frame' + str(f) + '.png +K.' + str(f) + '\n') # '+ stat +'
        condor_submit.write('Output = ' + str(f) + '.out\n')
        condor_submit.write('queue\n\n')

subprocess.call('condor_submit %s' % (fname,), shell=True)
```

What I don't understand is that I get the error saying there is no 'queue' command.

I opened up the created submit file and it shows up as..

```
universe=vanilla
....  (the rest of the header)
should_transfer_files = yes
when_to_transfer_files = on_exit

Arguments = test frame0.pov
Output = 0.out
queue

Arguments = test frame2.pov
```

and so on. Each section composed of argument, output, and queue does end with a queue statement and it is formatted like that.

What is causing it not to notice the queue lines?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get the same error if you call `condor_submit filetest.submit` manually?

Answer (score 1):

The data is likely buffered and not actually in the submit file yet. After you are done writing to the submit file either close the file or flush it before you invoke `condor_submit`.

The reason it is there after the program errors out and you inspect it is because the file is likely closed either (a) later in your program or (b) automatically at program exit.